# Visual Studio wrong code folding in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, code-folding

I am writing Python code in Visual Studio 2017, and I have some problems with code folding.

Sometimes, (not for all, but consistenly for specific folding points), when I collapse some code it takes also the code below.

For example something like this:

```
def fun1(): 
   pass

def fun2():
   pass
```

when folded is like in the image below

[image]

I tried to delete spaces, empty lines etc. between the two functions. I tried to close and reopen Visual Studio but the problem remains. How to fix this?